# Objective-C: How to solve a system of equations?

Tags: objective-c, equations

I need to write an app in Obj-C which solves systems of linear equations (the equations are entered by the user). What is the algorithm for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the code include comments or not :(

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev No, it isn't. It is for my iPhone app http://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/ishpora/id388459033?mt=8

Comment: @KevinDTimm you can include code if you want to

Comment: Then your question should've formulated thusly: where do I get an iPhone-compatible linear algebra library? This kind of problem has been solved so many times, DIY makes zero sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a thin Objective-C wrapper on top of [(c)lapack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK).
See [Computational Routines for Linear Equations in LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node26.html)

clapack should already be available in the iPhone, as part of the *Accelerate* framework (Accelerate contains vecLib which in turns contains clapack).

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to do this with clapack